# How it's possible to customize ion-tabs?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm doing a simple app with Ionic Framework, I'm using ion-tabs. I've already tried everything to customize my ion-tabs, but nothing works, can anyone help me showing a CSS?

I don't want ionic colors, like : positive, dark or assertive, I want to really customize it

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

    <!--To Do-->
    <ion-tab title="To Do" icon-off="ion-android-list" icon-on="ion-android-list" href="#/tab/todo">
        <ion-nav-view name="toDoView"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!--Done-->
    <ion-tab title="Done" icon-off="ion-android-checkbox" icon-on="ion-android-checkbox" href="#/tab/done">
        <ion-nav-view name="doneView"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!--Add To Do-->
    <ion-tab title="Add To Do" icon-off="ion-android-add-circle" icon-on="ion-android-add-circle" href="#/tab/add">
        <ion-nav-view name="addToDoView"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the **theme folder**, in the **variables.scss**, you can find in the line 26 the next code:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

inside this you can add something like that:

```
mynewcolor: #333131
```

your code it is going to look like this:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  mynewcolor: #333131
);
```

you can add all colors you want inside this variable.
After that, you can go to tabs.html and add it inside **ion-tabs**

```
<ion-tabs color="mynewcolor">
 //my tabs
</ion-tabs>
```

and that's it. You should see your new color in tabs.